# accepting only alphabets in varchar2 using check constraint in sql

Tags: constraints

I have a table with a column `name` of datatype `varchar2`. How can I use check constraint on `name` such that it will not accept NUMERIC VALUES AS WELL AS SPECIAL CHARACTERS in it?????

Comment: Does it make any sense to limit the range of characters for *names*? What about names such as 'Василий' or '‏יַעֲקֹב‎' or 'Πέτρος'?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ms sql

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD
CONSTRAINT column_alpha_check
CHECK
(
     field like '%[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%'
)
```

Also

In SQL you can enhance function to do [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)